# Flex 4 RichEditableText with right click menu

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, richeditabletext

I need selectable text that can be copied.
Some users are used to copy with Ctrl+C (Cmd+C on Mac), and some are used to right click and select "Copy".

Using s:RichEditableText, there is no "Copy" in right click menu: http://d.pr/xWXW
Using mx:Text, there is "Copy" in right click menu, but it doesn't copy anything: http://d.pr/vtiw

Ctrl+C works for both s:RichEditableText and mx:Text.

Is there a property or something to enable "Copy" in right click menu for s:RichEditableText?

Comment: this guy has a solution: http://blogagic.com/178/customizing-right-click-menu-of-flex-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either selectable or editable propery is set to "true" you are able to copy text from RichEditableText. But they are "true" by default...  So, I checked right-click context menu and "Copy" is in there (Flash Builder 4.5 Prem., Flash Player 10.3, Win7, Firefox).
First, I would try to clear and rebuild the project, and if it doesn't help try "right-clicking" on spark RichEditableText with default setting and plain-text content.

Comment: You're right. I tried with a clean project, and "Copy" is there. Must find out what's causing that menu to disappear in my project.